# Embedded Issuu publication not working in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, embed, issuu

Please view the problem at this link https://www.gmesupply.com/gme-catalog

The online catalog works on all browsers except for Google Chrome, where it just shows a blank screen.

Here is the code

```
<table id="container-catalog" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="680">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="tablecenter" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 680px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
<div>
<object style="width: 665px; height: 450px;" width="100" height="100" data="http://static.issuu.com/webembed/viewers/style1/v1/IssuuViewer.swf?mode=embed&amp;layout=http%3A%2F%2Fskin.issuu.com%2Fv%2Fdark%2Flayout.xml&amp;showFlipBtn=true&amp;documentId=130515160044-3470c4daf5234b85912b7707acb70a9a&amp;docName=gme_supply_summer_2013_catalog&amp;username=gmesupply&amp;loadingInfoText=GME%20Supply%20Summer%202013%20Full%20Product%20Catalog&amp;et=1368718407515&amp;er=72" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="data" value="http://static.issuu.com/webembed/viewers/style1/v1/IssuuViewer.swf?mode=embed&amp;layout=http%3A%2F%2Fskin.issuu.com%2Fv%2Fdark%2Flayout.xml&amp;showFlipBtn=true&amp;documentId=130515160044-3470c4daf5234b85912b7707acb70a9a&amp;docName=gme_supply_summer_2013_catalog&amp;username=gmesupply&amp;loadingInfoText=GME%20Supply%20Summer%202013%20Full%20Product%20Catalog&amp;et=1368718407515&amp;er=72" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="menu" value="false" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="src" value="http://static.issuu.com/webembed/viewers/style1/v1/IssuuViewer.swf?mode=embed&amp;layout=http%3A%2F%2Fskin.issuu.com%2Fv%2Fdark%2Flayout.xml&amp;showFlipBtn=true&amp;documentId=130515160044-3470c4daf5234b85912b7707acb70a9a&amp;docName=gme_supply_summer_2013_catalog&amp;username=gmesupply&amp;loadingInfoText=GME%20Supply%20Summer%202013%20Full%20Product%20Catalog&amp;et=1368718407515&amp;er=72" />
<param name="flashvars" value="mode=embed&amp;layout=http%3A%2F%2Fskin.issuu.com%2Fv%2Fdark%2Flayout.xml&amp;showFlipBtn=true&amp;documentId=130515160044-3470c4daf5234b85912b7707acb70a9a&amp;docName=gme_supply_summer_2013_catalog&amp;username=gmesupply&amp;loadingInfoText=GME%20Supply%20Summer%202013%20Full%20Product%20Catalog&amp;et=1368718407515&amp;er=72" />
</object>
<div style="width: 675px; text-align: left;"><a href="http://issuu.com/gmesupply/docs/gme_supply_summer_2013_catalog?mode=embed&amp;layout=http%3A%2F%2Fskin.issuu.com%2Fv%2Fdark%2Flayout.xml&amp;showFlipBtn=true" target="_blank"></a> <a href="http://issuu.com" target="_blank"></a><a href="http://issuu.com/search?q=capstan" target="_blank"></a></div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="tablecenterpad topborder" border="0" cellspacing="8" cellpadding="0" width="700" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;" width="320" align="center"><a href="http://www.gmesupply.com/pdf/GME_Supply_Summer_2013_Catalog.pdf" target="_blank"><img style="border: 0px currentColor;" src="http://www.gmesupply.com/images/download.png" alt="Download PDF" align="right" /></a>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;" width="350" align="center"><a onclick="window.open('http://www.gmesupply.com/catalog-request-form','popup','width=750,height=900,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0'); return false" href="http://www.gmesupply.com/catalog-request-form"><img style="border: 0px currentColor;" src="http://www.gmesupply.com/images/request.png" alt="Request by Mail" align="left" /></a>             </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are on an `https` site but trying to load `http` content.

Make sure to only include [protocol agnostic](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) or secure content (including the [secure version](https://e.issuu.com/embed.js) of 3rd party scripts like Issuu's) on your `https` site or browse your site in`http`, which seems to work fine in Chrome.